# Can't perform React state update on an unmounted component on making go to top btn

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-functional-component

im working on go to top button component and i dont understand what's going on.
isBtnShown controls styles to button

```
export const TopBtn = () => {
    const [isBtnShown, setIsBtnShown] = useState(false)

    const trackScroll = () => {
        if (!isBtnShown && window.pageYOffset > 400) {
            setIsBtnShown(true)
        } else if (isBtnShown && window.pageYOffset <= 400) {
            setIsBtnShown(false)
        }
    }

    const backToTop = () => {
        if (window.pageYOffset > 0) {
            window.scrollTo({ top: 0, behavior: 'smooth' })
        }
    }
    window.addEventListener('scroll', trackScroll)
    useEffect(() => {
        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener('scroll', trackScroll)
        }
    }, [])
    return (
        <button className={isBtnShown ? `${s.topBtn} ${s.shown}` : `${s.topBtn}`} onClick={backToTop}>
            <ChevronUpIcon />
        </button>
    )
}
```

here's error

> Warning: Can't perform a React state
> update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a
> memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and
> asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.
> at TopBtn (http://localhost:4000/src/features/TopBtn/TopBtn.jsx?t=1625128489631:21:39)
> at div

Comment: The `addEventListener` outside of the `useEffect` looks suspicious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', trackScroll)
    useEffect(() => {
        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener('scroll', trackScroll)
        }
    }, [])
```

should probably be

```
    useEffect(() => {
        const trackScroll = () => {
            if (!isBtnShown && window.pageYOffset > 400) {
                setIsBtnShown(true)
            } else if (isBtnShown && window.pageYOffset <= 400) {
               setIsBtnShown(false)
            }
        }
        window.addEventListener('scroll', trackScroll)
        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener('scroll', trackScroll)
        }
    }, [isBtnShown])
```

note, dependency on `isBtnShown`, and both the add and remove listener inside the `useEffect`